# Создать динамический список / чекбокс и лабель взаимосвязанны между собой /

Tags: c#, html

написав следующий код

```
@foreach (var item in Items)
{
    <div class="listSelector">
        @if (RowTemplate is not null)
        {
            <input type="checkbox" id="listId[intList]" name="item[intList]" value="listId[intList]" />
            <label for="listId[intList]">@RowTemplate(item)</label>
        }
    </div>

    intList++;

    var test = intList;
}

<style>
    .listSelector {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
</style>

@code
{
    public int intList { get; set; } = 0;
}
```

Я получаю список, `название и рядом чекбокс`

...только вот когда я нажимаю на лабель чтоб чекбокс подтвердить, происходит иногда сбой, поясню... через раз срабатывает, то он ставит галочку не на тот чекбокс то на нужный, я подумала, что если добавить какой то еще символ, чтоб каждый "пункт" списка был `уникальным`, добавила им переменную `intList` она меняет значение, только вот по моему это не очень исправило ситуацию и как то вообще коряво выглядит.

**Вопрос:** *Как можно создать такой "пункт" для списка, чтоб он был "динамическим" (чекбокс и лабель в каждом пункте) Множественный выбор из списка ?*

Comment: Я бы применил `for` вместо `foreach`, убрав `intList`.

Comment: ```foreach``` нужен, чтоб присвоить ```item``` ===> ```@RowTemplate(item)```

Comment: тк это отдельный компонент, и вызываю его с разных страниц, необходимо было создать ```RenderFragment``` "общий" чтоб потом его заполнить /```[Parameter] RenderFragment<TItem>? RowTemplate { get; set; }```

Comment: [вот по этому примеру делала](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Так это Blazor? Указывайте всю необходимую информацию в вопросе/метках. | А зачем RowTemplate? Это таблица? Не должны ли чекбокс и лейбл находится вместе внутри одного элемента? Сейчас получается, что чекбокс внутри div, а лейбл внутри RowTemplate.

Comment: думаю будет актуально для все проектов на сиШарп и html если будет ответ, поэтому в данном контексте блазор не обязательно имеет значение ? RowTemplate это типа списка/таблица/лист. Я на другой странице вызываю этот компонент и просто вместо RowTemplate вставляю свой список и все работает, но это ведь не суть вопроса, поэтому маловажная информация ?

Comment: _Не должны ли чекбокс и лейбл находится вместе внутри одного элемента_ можете просветлить ?

Comment: почему не RowTemplate в лейбл ? и оба они (чекбокс лейблом) в диве ?